# Regex Substitution find a link url

Tags: hyperlink

I would like to create a Substitution Regex that find a url in a test and give me in the substition like:

text text

text text https://example.com/texttexttext

text text text

and return me a test like this:

/fdu https://example.com/texttexttext

Answer (score 0):

This should capture the URL, without knowing more details of engine I'm not sure how to suggest substitution though.

```
(http[s]:\/\/[\w_-]+[\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])
```